# Application is stopped when trying to open webbrowser

Tags: android

I tried to open a url inside the phone's browser :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.ok :
            url = "http://www.moov.mg";
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            PriceActivity.this.startActivity(browserIntent);
            break;
    }
}
```

But I received an error alert stating that "Unfortunately, application_name has stopped".

What is wrong ?

Comment: How to open LogCat ? I use Eclipse ADT

Comment: Window-->show view-->Other...-->LogCat.

Comment: LogCat is blank ! even during running of the app

Comment: Try restarting eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I already wrote `import android.content.Intent;` so its not necessary to write `android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW`

Comment: Okay. then please share your Log. you can check log at Windows-->Showview-->other-->android-->logcat. If you still cannot see you log, plz restart you eclipse.

Comment: what choice should I choose in the listbox ? There are : verbose, debug, info, warn, error, assert ?

Comment: even if I choose error then restart eclipse then logcat is still blank when running the app !

Comment: the log should come, if we restart. sometimes we face the problem, But as i restart the eclipse i am able to see the logs. Please check your permissions..

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!url.startsWith("https://") && !url.startsWith("http://")){
    url = "http://" + url;
}
Intent openUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(openUrl);
```

Please also check if you have added the internet permission in manifest.

open your androidmanifest.xml and add permission to it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Still the same error , but it takes much time to the alert error to show :)

Comment: are you calling it from Activity or some class like adapter

Comment: from an Activity class

Comment: try ActivityName.this.startActivity(openUrl);

Comment: Clean your project once. Go to Project->Clean  and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
YourActivityName.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: error : `cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Activity`

Comment: then replace YourActivityName with your current context.

Comment: getApplicationContext() you mean ?

Comment: no, but try it, man you are calling this inside listener like onclick or inside activity that does not extends from activity, so please paste your full method here to check in order to help u.

Comment: I updated the code to show where I make the call ; yes its inside a listener method ( click of a button )